# Android - Single or Multiple Root View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In Android, is there one root view or multiple root views?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the context? An activity? A fragment? A `ListView`? Something else?

Comment: This is a temporary fix and not standard practice.  I'm referencing an Activity that is not under my working source code tree while I work on a full rewrite.

Comment: I'm in my own Activity and need to reference someone else's object in a different Activity and I cannot edit their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All activities have only one root view. You can reach it with `findViewById(android.R.id.content);` method.

Comment: Technically, that is not the root view, but the content view. The root view is above the content view (in terms of the view hierarchy) and will include things like the action bar. That being said, the content view will probably suffice for the OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

An `Activity` has one root view. You can obtain it via `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()`.